# How to replace individual words in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace, word-boundary

I need to replace words by substitutes given by an array as

```
$words = array(
'one' => 1,
'two' => 2,
'three' => 3
);

$str = 'One: This is one and two and someone three.';

$result = str_ireplace(array_keys($words), array_values($words), $str);
```

but this method changes `someone` to `some1`. I need to replace individual words.

Comment: You're missing at least one quote, and one semi-colon. Please make sure to provide accurate code examples so we can help you effectively.

Comment: @Chris sorry, my actual code was too complicated to be copied/pasted here, I wrote a simple one with typoes :p

Comment: regex would work better, but for simple string work, I'd just replace 'one' with ' one ' to encapsulate the spaces. Then change the output to ' 1 ' to match.

Comment: you need a regular expression so you can find the word boundaries

Comment: @Luke that  will fail to match the first "One" and the last "three"

Comment: @nogad yep. Terrible idea in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [word boundries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) in a regex to require a word match.

Something like:

```
\bone\b
```

would do it. [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with the [`i` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is what you'd want to use in PHP.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/GUxTWB/1

PHP Usage:

```
$words = array(
'/\bone\b/i' => 1,
'/\btwo\b/i' => 2,
'/\bthree\b/i' => 3
);
$str = 'One: This is one and two and someone three.';
echo preg_replace(array_keys($words), array_values($words), $str);
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/667239

Output:

> 1: This is 1 and 2 and someone 3.

Comment: Also maybe `'/\b'.implode('\b|', array_keys($words)).'\b/i'` to just have the words and not pattern in the array.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yea, could be a good alternative if the array structure can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \b as a word boundary in preg_replace:

```
foreach ($words as $k=>$v) {
  $str = preg_replace("/\b$k\b/i", $v, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will assist you replace some words but not characters in PHP  . It uses pre-replace() function

```
<?PHP
      function removePrepositions($text){
            
            $propositions=array('/\bthe\b/i','/\bor\b/i', '/\ba\b/i', '/\band\b/i', '/\babout\b/i', '/\babove\b/i'); 
        
            if( count($propositions) > 0 ) {
                foreach($propositions as $exceptionPhrase) {
                    $text = preg_replace($exceptionPhrase, '', trim($text));

                }
            $retval = trim($text);

            }
        return $retval;
    }
            
?>
```