# WordPress plugin to change part of a text PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

So for my class, I need to create a plugin for a blog tag shrinks the comments left in a post to 35 caracter max and change every occurence of the word "Hi" so it appear in bold and change the color to red. so far this is my code :

```
 add_filter('comment_text', 'shrink_text');

 function shrink_text($content) {
     $resultat = substr($content, 0, 35);
     return $resultat;
 }


add_action('comment_text', 'change_color');

function change_color($content){
    $source = array('/\bsalut\b/i' => 'Bonjour');
    
     echo preg_replace(array_keys($source), array_values($source), $content);
 }
```

So what I am missing here is how can i change every occurence of the word "Hi" so it is formated the way i have explain earlier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274790/how-to-replace-individual-words-in-a-string-in-php

Comment: And how could i change the color of the text if I may ask ?